# sql: comparting two tables with different values produces duplicated results

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to join/union two tables that have primary key, category, and a score, in such a way, that results will show the primary key and all categories and scores present in both tables together, and, if a given category is in only one table, then with a null for the score from the second table.

The tables are as follow:
opinion_1

```
fruit   category    score
apple   color   15
apple   sweet   50
apple   scent   35
orange  color   40
orange  sweet   60
```

opinion_2

```
fruit   category    score
apple   color   28
apple   sweet   12
orange  color   29
orange  sweet   50
orange  scent   31
```

I've tried full outer joining and double left joining with union, getting the same results with categories incorrectly multiplied.

```sql
WITH opinion_1 AS (
  SELECT 'apple' as fruit, 'color' as category, 15 as score UNION ALL
  SELECT 'apple',   'sweet',    50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'apple', 'scent',  35 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange', 'color', 40 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange', 'sweet', 60
), opinion_2 AS (
  SELECT 'apple' as fruit, 'color' as category, 28 as score UNION ALL
  SELECT 'apple',   'sweet',    12 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange', 'color', 29 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange', 'sweet', 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange', 'scent', 31
)
SELECT
  opinion_1.fruit,
  opinion_1.category as category,
  opinion_1.score as score1,
  opinion_2.score as score2
FROM opinion_1
full outer join opinion_2
on opinion_1.fruit = opinion_2.fruit
```

I expect the following result of the operation:

```
fruit   category    score1  score2
apple   color   15  28
apple   sweet   50  12
apple   scent   35  null
orange  color   40  29
orange  sweet   60  50
orange  scent   null    31
```

but I'm getting this:

```
fruit   category    score1  score2
apple   color   15  12
apple   color   15  28
apple   sweet   50  12
apple   sweet   50  28
apple   scent   35  12
apple   scent   35  28
orange  color   40  50
orange  color   40  31
orange  color   40  29
orange  sweet   60  50
orange  sweet   60  31
orange  sweet   60  29
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing a condition on your join to get the result you expect. Moreover, selecting `opinion_1.fruit` and `opinion_1.category` will produce nulls if there is no records for some fruit on opinion_1 whilst there are on opinion_2. The following query will produce the expected result :

```
WITH opinion_1 AS (
  SELECT 'apple' as fruit, 'color' as category, 15 as score UNION ALL
  SELECT 'apple',   'sweet',    50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'apple', 'scent',  35 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange', 'color', 40 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange', 'sweet', 60
), opinion_2 AS (
  SELECT 'apple' as fruit, 'color' as category, 28 as score UNION ALL
  SELECT 'apple',   'sweet',    12 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange', 'color', 29 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange', 'sweet', 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange', 'scent', 31
)
SELECT
  coalesce(opinion_1.fruit, opinion_2.fruit) as fruit,
  coalesce(opinion_1.category, opinion_2.category) as category,
  opinion_1.score as score1,
  opinion_2.score as score2
FROM opinion_1
full outer join opinion_2
on opinion_1.fruit = opinion_2.fruit and opinion_1.category = opinion_2.category
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH opinion_1 AS (
  SELECT 'apple' AS fruit, 'color' AS category, 15 AS score UNION ALL
  SELECT 'apple',   'sweet',    50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'apple', 'scent',  35 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange', 'color', 40 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange', 'sweet', 60
), opinion_2 AS (
  SELECT 'apple' AS fruit, 'color' AS category, 28 AS score UNION ALL
  SELECT 'apple',   'sweet',    12 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange', 'color', 29 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange', 'sweet', 50 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'orange', 'scent', 31
)
SELECT
  IFNULL(a.fruit, b.fruit) fruit,
  IFNULL(a.category, b.category) AS category,
  a.score AS score1,
  b.score AS score2
FROM opinion_1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN opinion_2 b
USING(fruit, category)
```

with result

```
Row fruit   category    score1  score2   
1   apple   color       15      28   
2   apple   sweet       50      12   
3   apple   scent       35      null     
4   orange  color       40      29   
5   orange  sweet       60      50   
6   orange  scent       null    31
```